# Python os.walk() not searching all file types

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to walk through a directory and list all the files using `os.walk`. The code that I have is this:

```
import sys
import os.path

def sourcedirs():
    print "Searching directory..."
    for dpath, dirs, files in os.walk(buildDir, followlinks=True):
        print files
        print len(files)
        for fileList in files:
            print fileList
            if '.cpp' in fileList:
                print fileList
            else:
                print "source files not found"
                sys.exit(1)

buildDir = os.getcwd()
print buildDir
sourcedirs()
```

Firstly, when I `print fileList` I get all the files that the directory has in the form of a list as shown below.

```
['test.py', 'template', 'SConsGenerator_version2.py', 'template-ORIGINAL-OLD', 'test.py~', 'SConsGenerator_version3.py~', 'SConsGenerator_version1.py', 'template-old', 'decomposePar.cpp', 'SConsscript', 'SConsGenerator_version3.py', 'template-ORIGINAL-NEW']
```

However, `print fileList` immediately after the second `for` loop (`for fileList in files:`) prints only

```
test.py
```

and the rest of the files are not being shown. It appears to be trivial, but I am unable to get whats going on here.

Comment: You will exit out as soon as you get a file without the regex match of .cpp in the else statement with  sys.exit what is your question here ? Look at the code where you are iterating through the file list during the first iteration will fail the if condition and exit out of the code maybe just have a continue instead or do nothing

Comment: I think the problem was `sys.exit(1)`. Thanks @cmidi

Comment: remove sys.exit(1) should work. it will stop the for loop.